# traverse though Javascript dom, details as attributes

Tags: javascript, xml

I have a XML file structured as below. All the data is saved as attributes(unfortunately I cannot alter the structure). And I am reading this into Javascript. I have the following code but I am having troubles relating each plant to an agent. I have tried ChildNodes but that does not seem to be working with attributes.

```
    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(reader.result,"text/xml");

    var i;
    for (i = 0;i<xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Agent").length;i++)
    {
        console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Agent")[i].attributes);

        for (....)//some for loop to look at every plant for that agent.
        {

        }
    }
```

And the XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
 <Agent Id="1" Type="typeA" Area="Area1">
  <Portfolio>
   <Plant Type="Type1" SubType="SubType1" />
   <Plant Type="Type2" SubType="SubType2" />
 </Portfolio>
</Agent>
<Agent Id="2" Type="typeB" Area="Area2">
 <Portfolio>
  <Plant Type="Type3" SubType="SubType3" />
  <Plant Type="Type4" SubType="SubType4" />  
 </Portfolio>
</Agent>
</root>
```

Comment: well it would seem that for each Agent you would need to go through the Portfolios first. you can not jump over the hierarchical structure of the XML. so your second for loop would be for Portfolios and in that one you have another for loop for the Plants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply get all elements with tag name `<Plant>` nested inside your `<Agent>` tag.

```
parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml,"text/xml");

// traverse agents
for (let agent of xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Agent"))
{
    //console.log(agent.attributes);

    // traverse plants
    for (let plant of agent.getElementsByTagName("Plant")) {
      console.log('agent:', agent.attributes, 'plant:', plant.attributes);
    }
}
```

Check out a live example here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6c4x530p/).

Answer (score 0):

```js
xml=`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
 <Agent Id="1" Type="typeA" Area="Area1">
  <Portfolio>
   <Plant Type="Type1" SubType="SubType1" />
   <Plant Type="Type2" SubType="SubType2" />
 </Portfolio>
</Agent>
<Agent Id="2" Type="typeB" Area="Area2">
 <Portfolio>
  <Plant Type="Type3" SubType="SubType3" />
  <Plant Type="Type4" SubType="SubType4" />  
 </Portfolio>
</Agent>
</root>`

parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml,"text/xml");

// traverse agents
for (let agent of xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Agent"))
{
   // console.log(agent.attributes);

    // traverse plants
    for (let plant of agent.getElementsByTagName("Plant")) {
      console.log('agent type:', agent.getAttribute('Type'),'agent Area:', agent.getAttribute('Area'));

console.log('plant type:',plant.getAttribute('Type'),' plant SubType:',plant.getAttribute('SubType'))
    }
}
```